# Kotlin JS built as JVM project resources with Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-js

Is it possible (if so, how I can do it?) using Gradle to compile Kotlin JS sources and then put them in Kotlin JVM project as jar resources?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this `build.gradle` script once to build a jar with those compiled resources:

```
import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask

plugins {
    id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "2.12.0"
}

def outDir = new File(buildDir, 'out')
def out = new File(outDir, 'name.js')
def min = new File(outDir, 'name.min.js')

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions {
        outputFile = out
        metaInfo = false
        noStdlib = true
        sourceMap = true
    }
}

task minifyKotlinJs(type : MinifyJsTask) {
    source = out
    dest = min
}

jar {
    from (outDir) {
        into("your/package/name")
        include '*.js', '*.map'
    }
    include 'META-INF', 'your'
}

minifyKotlinJs.dependsOn classes
jar.dependsOn minifyKotlinJs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what about JVM sources?